# Injecting jQuery css via a bookmarklet

Tags: jquery, css, bookmarklet

This will be a very dummy question, but... I want to add some css styles to a page, when browsing it, simply by clicking on a bookmarklet. It will save me some time :)

For instance, this code works :

```
javascript:void( jQuery( ".fancybox-overlay-fixed").css("background-color","black" ) );
```

But how come this one doesnt? It returns to me an error because of ";" before the second jquery.

```
javascript:void( jQuery( ".fancybox-overlay-fixed").css("background-color","black" ); jQuery( ".fancybox-close").css({ "display":"none"}); );
```

Any idea of how to adapt it, in order to add styles to more than 1 element?
Thanks !

Comment: replace `;` with `,` 
ex: `javascript:void( jQuery( ".fancybox-overlay-fixed").css("background-color","black" ), jQuery( ".fancybox-close").css({ "display":"none"}) );
`

Answer (score 1):

Replace ';' to ',' working good tested. Hope this help you.

```
javascript:void(  jQuery( ".fancybox-overlay-fixed").css("background-color","black" ), jQuery( ".fancybox-close").css({ "display":"none"}) );
```

Comment: I was pretty sure I tried it yesterday and it didnt work... but it seems to work now.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code :

```
$( ".fancybox-overlay-fixed").css("background-color","black" );
$( ".fancybox-close").css({ "display":"none"});
```

https://codepen.io/yakupov112/pen/LYVRdxp